# C# socket server drops some data when theres multiple messages

Tags: c#, sockets, server

Im trying to make a server for Unity 3d and it works fine until I try to update the players position. Once I try to update there position threw the server it drops parts of other messages im sending threw the server(even when the position update is only sent once a second).

Here is the server code (I got it from here https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1608/Asynchronous-Socket-Communication)

```
using System;
using System.Threading;                             // Sleeping
using System.Net;                                   // Used to local machine info
using System.Net.Sockets;                           // Socket namespace
using System.Collections;                           // Access to the Array list

namespace ChatServer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Main class from which all objects are created
    /// </summary>
    class AppMain
    {
        // Attributes
        private ArrayList   m_aryClients = new ArrayList(); // List of Client Connections
        /// <summary>
        /// Application starts here. Create an instance of this class and use it
        /// as the main object.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args"></param>
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppMain app = new AppMain();
            // Welcome and Start listening
            Console.WriteLine( "*** Chat Server Started {0} *** ", DateTime.Now.ToString( "G" ) );


            /*
            //
            // Method 1
            //
            Socket client;
            const int nPortListen = 399;
            try
            {
                TcpListener listener = new TcpListener( nPortListen );
                Console.WriteLine( "Listening as {0}", listener.LocalEndpoint );
                listener.Start();
                do
                {
                    byte [] m_byBuff = new byte[127];
                    if( listener.Pending() )
                    {
                        client = listener.AcceptSocket();
                        // Get current date and time.
                        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                        String strDateLine = "Welcome " + now.ToString("G") + "\n\r";

                        // Convert to byte array and send.
                        Byte[] byteDateLine = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( strDateLine.ToCharArray() );
                        client.Send( byteDateLine, byteDateLine.Length, 0 );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep( 100 );
                    }
                } while( true );    // Don't use this. 

                //Console.WriteLine ("OK that does it! Screw you guys I'm going home..." );
                //listener.Stop();
            }
            catch( Exception ex )
            {
                Console.WriteLine ( ex.Message );
            }
            */


            //
            // Method 2 
            //
            const int nPortListen = 5647;
            // Determine the IPAddress of this machine
            IPAddress [] aryLocalAddr = null;
            String strHostName = "";
            try
            {
                // NOTE: DNS lookups are nice and all but quite time consuming.
                strHostName = Dns.GetHostName();
                IPHostEntry ipEntry = Dns.GetHostByName( strHostName );
                aryLocalAddr = ipEntry.AddressList;
            }
            catch( Exception ex )
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Error trying to get local address {0} ", ex.Message );
            }

            // Verify we got an IP address. Tell the user if we did
            if( aryLocalAddr == null || aryLocalAddr.Length < 1 )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "Unable to get local address" );
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine( "Listening on : [{0}] {1}:{2}", strHostName, aryLocalAddr[0], nPortListen );

            // Create the listener socket in this machines IP address
            Socket listener = new Socket( AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );
            listener.Bind( new IPEndPoint( aryLocalAddr[0], nPortListen ) );
            //listener.Bind( new IPEndPoint( IPAddress.Loopback, 399 ) );   // For use with localhost 127.0.0.1
            listener.Listen( 1000);

            // Setup a callback to be notified of connection requests
            listener.BeginAccept( new AsyncCallback( app.OnConnectRequest ), listener );

            Console.WriteLine ("Press Enter to exit" );
            Console.ReadLine();
            //Console.WriteLine ("OK that does it! Screw you guys I'm going home..." );

            // Clean up before we go home
            listener.Close();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();      
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Callback used when a client requests a connection. 
        /// Accpet the connection, adding it to our list and setup to 
        /// accept more connections.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ar"></param>
        public void OnConnectRequest( IAsyncResult ar )
        {
            Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            NewConnection( listener.EndAccept( ar ) );
            listener.BeginAccept( new AsyncCallback( OnConnectRequest ), listener );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Add the given connection to our list of clients
        /// Note we have a new friend
        /// Send a welcome to the new client
        /// Setup a callback to recieve data
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sockClient">Connection to keep</param>
        //public void NewConnection( TcpListener listener )
        public void NewConnection( Socket sockClient )
        {
            // Program blocks on Accept() until a client connects.
            //SocketChatClient client = new SocketChatClient( listener.AcceptSocket() );
            SocketChatClient client = new SocketChatClient( sockClient );
            m_aryClients.Add( client );
            Console.WriteLine( "Client {0}, joined", client.Sock.RemoteEndPoint );

            // Get current date and time.
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            String strDateLine = "Welcome " + now.ToString("G") + "\n\r";

            // Convert to byte array and send.
            Byte[] byteDateLine = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( strDateLine.ToCharArray() );
            client.Sock.Send( byteDateLine, byteDateLine.Length, 0 );

            client.SetupRecieveCallback( this );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get the new data and send it out to all other connections. 
        /// Note: If not data was recieved the connection has probably 
        /// died.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ar"></param>
        public void OnRecievedData( IAsyncResult ar )
        {
            SocketChatClient client = (SocketChatClient)ar.AsyncState;
            byte [] aryRet = client.GetRecievedData( ar );

            // If no data was recieved then the connection is probably dead
            if( aryRet.Length < 1 )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "Client {0}, disconnected", client.Sock.RemoteEndPoint );
                client.Sock.Close();
                m_aryClients.Remove( client );                      
                return;
            }

            // Send the recieved data to all clients (including sender for echo)
            foreach( SocketChatClient clientSend in m_aryClients )
            {
                try
                {
                    clientSend.Sock.Send( aryRet );
                }
                catch
                {
                    // If the send fails the close the connection
                    Console.WriteLine( "Send to client {0} failed", client.Sock.RemoteEndPoint );
                    clientSend.Sock.Close();
                    m_aryClients.Remove( client );
                    return;
                }
            }
            client.SetupRecieveCallback( this );
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Class holding information and buffers for the Client socket connection
    /// </summary>
    internal class SocketChatClient
    {
        private Socket m_sock;                      // Connection to the client
        private byte[] m_byBuff = new byte[1000];       // Receive data buffer
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sock">client socket conneciton this object represents</param>
        public SocketChatClient( Socket sock )
        {
            m_sock = sock;
        }

        // Readonly access
        public Socket Sock
        {
            get{ return m_sock; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Setup the callback for recieved data and loss of conneciton
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="app"></param>
        public void SetupRecieveCallback( AppMain app )
        {
            try
            {
                AsyncCallback recieveData = new AsyncCallback(app.OnRecievedData);
                m_sock.BeginReceive( m_byBuff, 0, m_byBuff.Length, SocketFlags.None, recieveData, this );
            }
            catch( Exception ex )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "Recieve callback setup failed! {0}", ex.Message );
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Data has been recieved so we shall put it in an array and
        /// return it.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ar"></param>
        /// <returns>Array of bytes containing the received data</returns>
        public byte [] GetRecievedData( IAsyncResult ar )
        {
            int nBytesRec = 0;
            try
            {
                nBytesRec = m_sock.EndReceive( ar );
            }
            catch{}
            byte [] byReturn = new byte[nBytesRec];
            Array.Copy( m_byBuff, byReturn, nBytesRec );

            /*
            // Check for any remaining data and display it
            // This will improve performance for large packets 
            // but adds nothing to readability and is not essential
            int nToBeRead = m_sock.Available;
            if( nToBeRead > 0 )
            {
                byte [] byData = new byte[nToBeRead];
                m_sock.Receive( byData );
                // Append byData to byReturn here
            }
            */
            return byReturn;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different types of communication applications 1) Chat 2) Command and Control.

A chat application uses your brain to separate where a start and end of each message is located.  A chat application two users can type at the same time and your brain can easily figure out how to put the message back together and interpret.

A Command and Control Application you have to write the intelligence into the code.

First a TCP message does not come in one chunk.   TCP specification has max chunk size of 1500 bytes and routers and server can break chunks into smaller pieces and combine smaller pieces into large pieces. So you cannot process a chunk until you get the entire messages.

So then you have to a protocol for determining the end of message.  Text message you can terminate with a character that is not in the message like a return or EOX.

Binary data you have to proceed the message with a byte count.

So you current code cannot handle chunks.  Current code immediately processes pieces of a message and fails.  So you have to add to each message either a byte count at beginning of message or terminate each message with a character.  Then modify the receive code to wait until a complete message is received before processing.

Answer (score 0):

I found this and it works great for getting full messages. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11922/Solution-for-TCP-IP-client-socket-message-boundary